# HTML and CSS: rounded corners on tables

Tags: html, css, border, radius

I have a bit of a problem. I would like all corners of my table to be rounded, however the dark rows seem to still have a pointy border. Thanks for your help!

[image: The Problem:]

```
.table_background {
    display: flex;
    background-color: white;
    margin-left: 3vw;
    margin-right: 3vw;
    margin-bottom: 10vh;
    margin-top: 5vh;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(114, 114, 113, 0.5);
    border-radius: 15px;
}

table {
    font-family: futura-pt, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 15px;
}

th {
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
}

table,
td {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 20px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #eff2f5;
}

tr:not(:first-child):hover {
    background-color: rgba(114, 114, 113, 0.2);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add "overflow:hidden" on the table itself:

```
table {
    font-family: futura-pt, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 15px;

    /* add this */
    overflow:hidden
}
```

Comment: Works great! Thank you so much :)

Can I ask why this is a problem only on every other row?

Comment: Because every other row has a background. The rest of them are transparent. All rows have sharp edges, though, so if you put a background to the other rows, you will still see this effect. So you need to make sure the rounded corners container (`table`) cuts the rows like a cookie cutter, by adding the `overflow:hidden`

Comment: Thanks so much for your advice!

Answer (score 3):

set `overflow:hidden` from `table`. Try this

```
table {
font-family: futura-pt, sans-serif;
font-weight: 400;
font-style: normal;
border-collapse: collapse;
width: 100%;
border-radius: 15px;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```html
table {
border-collapse: collapse;
width: 100%;
border-radius: 15px;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, including an explanation of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.